# Match unique string in PHP between common characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do some string matching in PHP. I have the following url string in a variable:

```
phones/gift.nintendo-3ds/handset.blackberry-9790.html
```

I want remove the `/gift.nintendo-3ds` from the above, but the gift will always be different.

Any ideas? I want the url variable to look like this after each call different gifts:

```
phones/handset.blackberry-9790.html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input  = 'phones/gift.nintendo-3ds/handset.blackberry-9790.html';
$output = preg_replace('(gift\.[^/]*\/)', '', $input);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/\/gift\.[^/]*/', '', $url);
```

Matches /gift. then anything till the next slash and replaces it with blank.

Comment: $url = 'phones/gift.nintendo-3ds/handset.blackberry-9790.html'; $url = preg_replace('/\/gift\.[^/]*/', '', $url);

Answer (score 0):

You could split it apart, remove the second part you do not want to keep and then concat it again:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url, 3);
unset($parts[1]);
$result = implode('/', $parts);
```

This is not using any regular expression as you might have thought about but probably tells you about some other useful functions.

Demo: http://codepad.org/a1pNW8J6

A regex variant could be:

```
echo preg_replace('~^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)~', '$1', $url);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/vyR04xMn